# Round icon is not changing in Android Studio 3.0

Tags: android, android-manifest

Launcher icon changed but round icon not changing, it showing default icon by android studio when I click recent tab of android phone.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

[Icon on recent app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euYSi.png)

Answer (score 7):

**Remove the XML file inside**

*res >> mipmap >> ic_launcher >> ic_launcher.xml*

or

*res >> mipmap >> ic_launcher_round >> ic_launcher_round.xml*

Answer (score 1):

change round icon name like logo_round
and use this code.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/logo_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: Did this not even changed.

Comment: put a round logo in mipmap folder with name logo_round

Comment: Yes i have it. Its not working then I changed it to logo only.